# HTML split a list in multiple columns

Tags: html-lists

I'm trying to divide my list into multiple columns.

Example:

```
<ul class="loremipsum">
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 01</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 02</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 03</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 04</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 05</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 06</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 07</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem farem 08</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 09</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 10</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 11</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 12</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 13</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 14</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 15</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum 16</a></li>
</ul>
```

Lorem ipsum 01 Lorem ipsum 06 Lorem ipsum 11 Lorem ipsum 16

Lorem ipsum 02 Lorem ipsum 07 Lorem ipsum 12 etc

Lorem ipsum 03 Lorem ipsum 08 Lorem ipsum 13

Lorem ipsum 04 Lorem ipsum 09 Lorem ipsum 14

Lorem ipsum 05 Lorem ipsum 10 Lorem ipsum 15

This is not a problem with jquery as I have found "Easy List Splitter".
However, this does not provide me with what I need.

The problem with the script of "Easy List Splitter" is that I need to put in an amount of columns. This is a problem for me because I'll be adding new items to this list weekly (if not daily) at the top of the list. It would mean I would need to edit the js file everytime.

Now that wouldn't even be a big problem (editting the amount of columns).
However, some of these list items (maybe 1 out of 10) is an image link.

What I would like to accomplish is this (numbers are just examples):

- a wrapper div with 300px height
- each list item has a min-height of 60px
- max. 5 items per column
- min. 1 item per column ofcourse
- any column (left, right or the center) should be able to have only 1 list item if that 1 list item is 300px height for example (or 2 of 150px etc)
- must be a vertical list
- new column automatically created on the right of the other columns

A better question is........is this possible?
If new DIV's would show below/on top of eachother instead of next to eachother, the problem was solved already.

Big big thanks in advance!

If any more questions, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest solution I found is to make LI float left and assign a width of 33% (for 3 columns) but it will not fill a column before starting another. The CSS Indeed is not complex.

```
.loremipsum li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cSJNm/

Comment: true indeed and it would not create a 4th column automatically when I add more LI's.. thanks for your input though! I think jquery will be needed for this

Comment: if need some help with jQuery feel free to ask.

Comment: Many thanks for the offer Edorka! I'll try Bartdude's method first to see if it works the way I need it. If not, can I still ask for your assistance?

Comment: Sure, I'm reading his response, interesting. Anyway I put an example

Answer (score 0):

You might find some interest in [this W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) about Multiple-Column layout which [you can already use](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn) (with some prefixes though) on modern browsers.

Maybe not exactly what you would have wanted, but I think this is the best solution for your problem at the moment...

Comment: This looks pretty promising! Ill have to test if it is indeed what I need, thanks a lot! Ill let you know